# Вынос картинки за пределы формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли средствами C# сделать так, чтобы часть изображения было за пределами формы? Пример ниже:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю на счет winforms, но в wpf можно сделать прозрачное диалоговое окно с картинкой и воткнуть его куда нужно, думаю нужно поиграть с прозрачностью диалогового окна.

Comment: Рекомендую вам изучить руководство: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6k15y9et(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: А в целом, с вашими запросами, вам реально будет проще все реализовать все хотелки, используя **WPF**, если вы использует **.NET**

Comment: Надо изучать эту тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так, как предложили в комментариях. Надо будет делать дополнительную форму, в ресурсы добавить картинку с прозрачным фоном и поставить ее на задний фон. Код будет примерно следующий (здесь картинка вставляется программно):

```
public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BackgroundImage = FormTransform.Properties.Resources._6;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.AllowTransparency = true;
    this.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue; 
    this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
}
```

Вот что-то похожее на это у вас должно получиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Поправил код согласно комментария [Seedorf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204541/seedorf). Спасибо за совет.

Comment: Минус у этого способа заключается в том, что внизу, рядом с пуском видно, что появляется вторая форма

Comment: Этого можно избежать, изменив у формы свойство Showln Taskbar  на false